# The verb after "thereby"

Tags: adverbs, gerunds

I wrote:

> This may be important in the context of anionic complexes extraction from water because the positive potential on the interface attracts anionic complexes to the interface, **thereby increases/increasing** their concentration at the interface and facilities **transfer of them** to the IL phase via an ion exchange mechanism.

Is it "increases" or "increasing" after "thereby"? The sentence may seem too long, however, I don't know how to shorten it. Moreover, I am not sure about "transfers of them". Could it be "their transfer" or just "transfer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, "thereby" makes no difference.  The conjugation is the same with or without it.

> The captain adjusted the boat's sails, (thereby) **increasing** its speed through the water.

With this shorter example it should be easier to see that "increases" doesn't work, because there is no subject doing the increasing.  I'm afraid I don't know the name of this grammar structure (might be a gerund phrase) but it's a consequence of the main clause.  Another example:

> Paul wedged the crowbar into the door, **opening** it a bit wider.

However as JeremyC mentions in his answer:  In a parallel structure, whatever form you use for the first verb, you should use for the second.  "Increasing" should match with "facilitating".  Example:

> The enzyme neatly binds to the receptor, **increasing** permeability **and facilitating** the transfer of ATP across the cell membrane.

Your sentence is long, but not unusually long.  The only thing I'd remove from it is "of them".  The rest sounds fine.

> thereby increasing their concentration at the interface and facilitating transfer to the IL phase via an ion exchange mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern here is: A does something, as a result of which something else happens. "He stirred his coffee, thereby mixing the cream into it." 
If you try to say "...thereby mixes..." the verb mixes does not have a subject in the second clause.

Do you mean 'facilitate' rather than 'facilities'? Assuming you do, the words  should be "...increasing..." and "...facilitating...".

I don't think that 'transfer of them ' is actually wrong, but it is clunky and 'their transfer' is fine.

Comment: Agreed. I would also recommend changing "anionic complexes extraction". So — "This may be important in the context of extracting anionic complexes from water, because the positive potential on the interface attracts anionic complexes to the interface, thereby increasing their concentration at the interface and facilitating their transfer to the IL phase via an ion exchange mechanism."